# Function of products and product of functions are equal?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, product-space

Say $h:\prod X_{\alpha}\rightarrow \prod X_{\alpha}$ and $\space h(x)=(h_{\alpha}(x_{\alpha}))$, $U = \prod U_{\alpha}$ is an open set in $\prod X_{\alpha}$.

It's $h(U) = \prod (h_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}))$ true? What if $U$ is only open in $\prod X_{\alpha}$

If it's true, why? What if $h(U)$ is a union of different cubes (or square, a visualization that helps me understand for a product of 2 $X_{\alpha}$)?

If it's wrong, is this true if $U$ is a basis? $h(U)$ can still be a union of different cubes even if $U$ itself is a cube right?

I'm really confused, appreciate it!

Comment: Your second saying is wrong.

Comment: If $h$ is of the form $h(x)=\big(h_\alpha(x_\alpha)\big)$, i.e. $h=\prod h_\alpha$, and $A=\prod A_\alpha$ then indeed $h(A)=\prod h_\alpha (A_\alpha)$. Regardless of what $A$ and $A_\alpha$ are. You can check this by hand, simply by considering two inclusions.